# How to disable mouse click events on disabled html elements in meteor / javascript

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, dom-events

I'm using meteor. I have a bunch of buttons that are currently disabled. I have an event listener that opens a modal on click of the button. Right now, the state of these buttons are `disabled`. Even so, when I click on the disabled button, the modal still opens up. Doesn't disabling an element prevent any events that are generated from it?

**Template:**

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-default" id="{{name}}" name ="editRole"
   disabled="disabled" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"
   title="Not available right now">
  <em class="fa fa-pencil"></em>
</a>
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" id={{name}} name="deleteRole"
   disabled="disabled"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"
   title="Not available right now">
  <em class="fa fa-trash"></em>
</a>
```

**Template events:**

```
'click [name=editRole]'(event){
        Session.set("editRole",$(this).attr('name'));
        console.log("The role to be edited is: " + Session.get("editRole"));
        Modal.show('editRoleModal');
    },
'click [name=deleteRole]'(event){
        console.log(this);
        console.log("button clicked is: " + $(this).attr('name'));
        Session.set("deleteRole", $(this).attr('name'));
        Modal.show('confirmRoleDeleteModal');
    }
```

The only way I figured was to add disabled class like below:

The `disabled="disabled"` only seems to gray out the icons but still generates events while `class="... disabled"` seems to prevent events.

Comment: You cannot disable an `a` element - hence the `disabled` attribute has no effect, other than making your HTML invalid. To stop the mouse event working, attach an event handler to the element and use `event.preventDefault()` on it, check for a `data-disabled` attribute on the element in your existing click handlers or use `pointer-events: none` in a CSS class which you toggle on/off as needed. Although be aware that `pointer-events` is not well supported in IE <11

Comment: I just edited my question. I've added a few more details I found working

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - If you could put the comment as an answer, I can upvote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot disable an a element - hence the `disabled` attribute has no effect, other than making your HTML invalid.

To stop the mouse event working, attach an event handler to the element and use `event.preventDefault()` on it, check for a `data-disabled` attribute on the element in your existing click handlers or use `pointer-events: none` in a CSS class which you toggle on/off as needed. Although be aware that `pointer-events` is not well supported in IE <11